# What is a working method for extracting numeric values with associated data from open text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to look for a solution but nothing was giving me quite what I needed. I'm not sure regex can do what I need.

I need to process a large amount of data where license information is provided. I just need to grab the number of licenses and the name for each license then group and tally the license counts for each company.

Here's an example of the data pulled:

```
L00129A578-E105C1D138   1 Centralized Recording 

$42.00
L00129A677-213DC6D60E   1 Centralized Recording 

$42.00
1005272AE2-C1D6CACEC8   5 Station   

$45.00
100525B658-3AC4D2C93A   5 Station   

$45.00
```

I would need to grab the license count and license name then add like objects so it would grab (1 Centralized Recording, 1 Centralized Recording, 5 Station, 5 Station) then add license counts and output (2 Centralized Recording, 10 Station)

What would be the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I looked into Regex but it doesn't seem capable of pulling the license names with the numeric values. I have been using an excel formula but it's still tedious work, I'm hoping there's an easy way to do it with Python. I know a bit of AutoPy but not enough to do what I need to do.

Comment: Well, which regexes have you tried? I'm no regex whiz either, but something like `[A-Z0-9]{10}-[A-Z0-9]{10}` seems to work for the sample data you provided.

Comment: My apologies, could you please give me a complete example of the code that I can play with and figure out? I don't mind figuring stuff out and learning but regex seems a bit difficult to just jump into without an example to work with.

Comment: For sure, you can use https://regex101.com to experiment with it :)

Comment: Can you show the desired format of output you want for the given data?

Comment: The desired format would be something like:
60 MaxCommunicator Session
1 MaxMobile
99 Softswitch Station
12 SIP Trunking Session License
7 Polycom ADV SEAT LIC
12 G.711/G.723/G.729 VoIP Channels
7 Third Party SIP Device Seat
1 Softswitch Combo Base

Comment: I just need the number of total licenses for a specific type of license and the license name next to it. Nothing fancy. The number of licenses will always be different but there is only 20 or so different names for the licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to ignore the license number, and get the count and name. So, the following should point you on your way for your data, if it is as uniform as it seems:

```py
import re
r = re.compile(r"\s+(\d+)\s+[A-Za-z ]+")
r = re.compile(r"\s+(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+)")
m = r.search(" 1   Centralized")
m.groups()
# ('1', 'Centralized')
```

That regex just says, "Require but ignore 1 or more spaces, pay attention to the string of digits after it, require but ignore 1 or more spaces after it, and pay attention to the capital letters, lower case letters, and spaces after it." (You may need to trim of a newline when you're done.)

The file-handling bit would look like:

```py
f = open('/path/to/your_data_file.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    # run regex and do stuff for each line
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is close. How do I import the text file that needs to be searched using this code?

Comment: That's the `f = open('your_data_file.txt')` line. And `f.readlines()` will give you one line at a time.

Comment: So I have the python file in the same folder as the excel file and the code is:

import re

f = open(Basic SAP for agreements.xlsx)
for line in f.readlines():
    # run regex and do stuff for each line
 r = re.compile(r"\s+(\d+)\s+[A-Za-z ]+")
 r = re.compile(r"\s+(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+)")
 m = r.search(" 1   Centralized")
 m.groups()
    pass

When I run the program it just closes instantly and doesn't do anything

Comment: The `m.groups()` line was to show you what the output of the search is, when it is successful. It's up to you, as a programmer, to go "Oh, so that's what I get out of it. Those are the parts I need. I can go from here." The `pass` line is just so that the example will compile for you. It's the comment "run regex and do stuff for each line" that is meant to spur you on to put your own logic in there. You'll have to get the pieces, track the totals (HINT: defaultdict(int)), and so on.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you said "excel file" in your initial post. I was assuming strings in a text file. That's the way I would go, if I were you. If it exports as a .csv file, you'll have commas in there, and you'll have to tweak the regex. Either way, it's definitely doable. (Jeez. If it's an excel file, you can probably do it in Excel!)

Comment: Lol I got close to what I needed with just Excel, but it's still slowing me down. I am needing to copy the info for each client into notepad and add tabs in-between each license count number and license name then process in excel then copy out of excel into a word document. It works, but it's slow. The formula I'm using in Excel is =SUMIF(C1:C396,"Station",B1:B396)+SUMIF(C1:C396," Station",B1:B396)

Comment: You should be able to export the file as a .csv file from within Excel. I believe it's `File -> Export` or `File -> Save as...`

Comment: Thanks for working with me. I'm still new to Python and am most comfortable using PyAutoGUI so I ended up using only PyAutoGUI, functools, and collections to accomplish my needs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re, io, pandas as pd
a = open('your_data_file.txt')
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(re.sub(r'(?m).*\s(\d+)\s+(.*\S+)\s+$\n|.*','\\1,\\2',a)),
                header=None).groupby(1).sum()[0].to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is a good tool for jobs like this. You might have to play around with it a bit. You will also need to export your excel file as a .csv file. In the interpreter,try:

```
import pandas
raw = pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv')
print(raw.columns)
```

That will give you the column headings for the csv file. If you have headers name and nums, then you can extract those as a list of tuples as follows:

```
extract = list(zip(raw.name, raw.nums))
```

You can then sort this list by name:

```
extract = sorted(extract)
```

Pandas probably has a method for compressing this easily, but I can't recall it so:

```
def accum(c):
    nm = c[0][0]
    count = 0
    result = []
    for x in c:
        if x[0] == nm:
            count += x[1]
        else:
            result.append((nm, count))
            nm = x[0]
            count = x[1]
    result.append((nm, count))
    return result

done = accum(extract)
```

Now you can write this to a text file as follows(fstrings require Python 3.6+)

```
with open("myjob.txt", "w+") as fout:
      for x in done:
          line = f"name: {x[0]}    count: {x[1]} \n"
          fout.write(line)
```